# C: Passing variable down the functions, is this design valid?

Tags: c

This question may appear too basic, but please do look at it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f3(int *p) {
    *p = 100;
}

void f2(int *p) {
    f3(p);
}

void f1(int *p) {
    f2(p);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a;
    f1(&a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, the address of a stack variable (`a`) is passed to multiple functions down the call stack where its value is changed at the last function.

Is this way of changing values a good design? If not, what should be a better design?

My question arises because with a Heap variable (say `a` being a heap variable as shown below), this design is OK since the allocated memory is "global" to all functions.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*1);
    f1(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    free(a)
    return 0;
}
```

But with a local variable, I'm doubtful if 2 levels down the call stack, its still valid to access the memory with just a single level pointer.
Should I pass another level of pointer down each function call? (like `f1(&a)` then `f2(&p)` and so on).

Comment: `f2(&p)` would pass the wrong address: the location where `int *p` is stored, not the location where `int a` is stored. The compiler should warn you if you try that.

Comment: Yes, I just meant in that case I'd change the function definitions to take pointer-to-pointer and such.

Comment: The code was correct. It passes a pointer around.

Comment: Re the edit: it makes no difference *where* `a` is or how it was obtained.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Unrelated question: The question I asked seems way too basic. Should I take it down or reword it in a way that its more accessible while searching?

Comment: The problems come if you try to pass the address of a local variable up the call stack; the variable does not exist after the function returns.  Passing the address down the stack — to functions called by the function where the variable is defined — is not a problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Makes sense. Since the function call stack is popped, the local variables associated with the function are also absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is absolutely correct. The variable a exists all the time, and f3 will receive the address of variable a. No problem at all.